# Adding dynamic row jquery having dynamic dropdown in php

Tags: php, jquery

I am using the following jquery code to add new rows but thing is I have couple of static fields and couple of dynamic fields being populated using php.

```
$(document).on('click', '#add', function(){ 
        if(i < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
            i++;
            var product_dd = '<select name="product_id[]" id="product_id"><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($products_list); ?></select>';
            var category_dd = '<select name="category_id[]" id="category_id"><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($category_list); ?></select>';

            $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added"><td><input id="item_type" pattern="[2-3]*" type="text" required maxlength="1" name="item_type[]" /></td><td>'+product_dd+'</td><td>'+category_dd+'</td><td><select name="status[]" id="status"><option value="1" selected="selected">Enabled</option><option value="0">Disabled</option></select></td><td></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
        }

    });
```

The rows are being inserted as I need but the problem I am facing is that the two drop downs are blank, I have checked the php function and it is returning all the options I need, but not sure when I click 'Add More' button why the drop downs are blank. Any help please!

here is the php code used to generate the drop downs, which is working fine, I already tested that.

```
function fill_select_box($products_list)
    {    
         $output = '';   
         foreach($products_list as $key => $value)
         {
          $output .= '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
         }
         return $output;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: @marcelo2605 i am trying something like this, which seems to be working. https://www.webslesson.info/2017/10/add-remove-select-box-fields-dynamically-using-jquery-ajax-in-php.html

Comment: Inside `fill_unit_select_box()`, try return some dummy content to check if it populate the options.

Comment: Where is PHP code?

Comment: I tried with dummy code and it works fine. You need to see the php code that generates the drop down?

Comment: You tagged it as PHP question. Do I need to see your PHP code?

Comment: @Just_Do_It. So the PHP function is working. Maybe the problem is in your database query. Share your PHP code and test your query using PHPMyAdmin or similar.

Comment: What does the final JS look like? Posting stuff with `<?php echo...?>` doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: No, the final output that you see in the browser, without the PHP code.

Comment: I see just this <select name="product_id[]" id="product_id"></select> @miken32

Comment: Then that tells you your PHP isn't outputting anything, doesn't it?

Comment: @miken32 plz check the screenshot the initial row is fine, populated with all the data I need which clearly shows php code working fine, when I clone using jquery I get blank drop downs.